# Should you use this. in reference to a property in factory functions?

Tags: javascript, function, this, factory

everyone, i am trying to wrap my head around factory functions. I want to know what is the proper way to make a factory function that takes in a parameter.

Should the methods we give the objects that it creates refer to its properties by using this. in front on them?

For example:

```
//using this. 
function createPerson(name) {
    return {
        name,
        talk() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }
}
```

or this way:

```
//not using this. 
function createPerson(name) {
    return {
        name,
        talk() {
            console.log(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both and they both seem to perform the same way, which I assume I am probably wrong about. Meaning if i run the following:

```
const marc = createPerson('marc');
const joe = createPerson('joe');
marc.talk();
joe.talk();
```

in both cases I get the same output, so is it necessary to use this. in the factory function? What is the common practice? thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is working with `this` only because the returned object has that `name` property.

The context of `this` is the returned object and not the createPerson function object

If you were to have a variable outside the object and try to access it with `this` it won't work.

The context of `this` can be compicated and I think that you can easily get confused knowing what `this` is in your use case

```js
//not using this. 
function createPerson(name) {
    // without using new createPerson() "this" is not the function object
    const upper = this.upper = name.toUpperCase();

    return {
        name,
        talk() {
            console.log('this.upper', this.upper)
            console.log('upper', upper);
        }
    }
}

const foo= createPerson('foo')
foo.talk()
```

Comment: Thanks i understand better now!